# Spring @Component not reading .properties field properly

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I've got several `@Configuration` classes which do specify custom `@ConfigurationProperties("sample")` and are used within to instantiate several beans that are going to be used my business logic classes later on.

However, I've been trying to do this approach with an inner `@Component` class so I don't need to fit that within an existing specific or generic config and see what happens.

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("myclass")
public class MyClass  {

     private String attribute;        

     (Constructor, getters and setters for attribute and other methods...)

}
```

And within my `application.properties` file I do specify that attribute value as `myclass.attribute=value`.

Doing it this way results in a null value everytime. Do `@Component` accept reading .properties file or should it still be in a `@Configuration` class?

Comment: Did you add `@EnableConfigurationProperties` to one of your configuration classes?

Comment: Yes @daniu, that notation enables them in one of the base configs that is always instantiated.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier just add `@Value("myclass.attribute")`?

Comment: Same story @dehasi, still getting null value.

Comment: try with @propertySource("classpath:application.properties")  and @Value("myclass.attribute")

Comment: @MangduYogii same... There must be some other annotation making conflict or something, this can't be possible that all your answers don't work :(

Comment: possibly due to problem in applicationContext.xml vs spring-servlet.xml - it was scoping issue between the beans.

Comment: just needed to fix the context:component-scan in my app context XML and spring servlet XML

Comment: @MangduYogii I'm using Spring Cloud Streams also. Just did a quick try forcing the variable to the major config class and then trying Autowired in the class. When checking the Bean instantiation the value is properly set, however, when injected within the class that I need it is still null. May be what you just said about scopes?

Comment: you are using spring-boot for this right?

Comment: @MangduYogii yes I do.

Answer (score 1):

I should have put it as a comment. But didn't want someone to miss this trivial thing.

> Okay the issue is - You are missing the '$' (DOLLAR SYMBOL). Wondering why nobody noticed it?

In your properties file if you have this :

```
myclass.attribute=value
```

Then to access it in any class, do this:

```
@Value("${myclass.attribute}")
```

Noticed the $ symbol above??

Comment: This ain't working either, still null. There must be some conflict that I'm missing out.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is working as expected, even using `@ConfigurationProperties` in class annotated with `@Component`. Please try :

application.properties :

```
myclass.attribute=value
```

MyClass class :

```
@Data
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("myclass")
public class MyClass {
    private String attribute;
}
```

Test class :

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class FooTests {

    @Autowired
    private MyClass myClass;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        System.out.println(myClass.getAttribute());
    }
}
```

Comment: No luck so far, same 'nul' as before. I'm also trying it launching the service setting a breakpoint where the variable is used (within the class that defines it).

What's the @Data notation? Can't find a package that includes it.

Comment: it's lombok library for replacing getters & setters with this annotation.

Answer (score 0):

You do need the `@EnableConfigurationProperties` annotation on on of you configuration classes, eg the application class.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public class MySpringBootApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MySpringBootApp.class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never used the `@ConfigurationProperties` annotation but if you want to set your attribute from a value in your `application.properties` I'll recommend using the `@Value` annotation :

application.properties :

```
myclass.attribute=foo
```

```
@Component
public class MyClass  {

     @Value("myclass.attribute")
     private String attribute;     

     // ...
}
```

This way every instance of `MyClass` will have `attribute` with the default value `foo`

Comment: Same story when using that annotation, null value.